# I need wxpython on Ubuntu 11.10, how do i get it

Tags: python, downloads

I have a program that requires wxpython, but the site for wxpython only covers Ubuntu upto 11.04. It requires u to list the name or your distribution in the command for the installation (ie. 11.04=natty). Is there any way for me to get wxpython?

I am on a HP with 3 GB of ram and a 2.7 Dual core.
I am running Ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 1):

The package python-wxgtk2.8 dependencies state that this package replaces the package wxpython2.6-0 ; does this package meet your needs?